# Julia set on Riemann sphere

Tags: graphics, complex, fractals

How to draw Julia sets of rational functions on Riemann sphere, the inbuilt mathematica command draws it on complex plane.

Edit: My question is marked a duplicate by many learned people but when I went to the so called duplicate it was about the Newton maps, My question is about arbitrary rational map, not about the basin of roots in Newton maps.

Comment: My question is marked a duplicate by many learned people but when I went to the so called duplicate it was about the Newton maps, My question is about arbitrary rational map, not about the basin of roots in Newton maps.

Comment: I agree that the linked question is not an *exact* duplicate. However, a one sentence question whose answer is essentially a programming project is likely to be closed as too broad or out of scope anyway. At the very least, this question should provide some non-Newton's method based examples of what you'd like to accomplish. Further, my answer to the linked question, defines a function called `limitInfo` that, in principle, could be modified to iterate until periodicity is detected. The rest of the code should work unaltered.